# Can I use auth/sveltekit to secure a connection between front end and back end

Tags: authentication, sveltekit

I currently have a sveltekit front end which connects to nextjs back end API's. I set it up initially using basic authorization and now want to secure via either "credentials:'include'"  or bearer token as I believe this will be more secure. I already use auth/sveltekit to authenticate the users at the front end so I thought I would start with this.

I have access to the encrypted authentication cookie, and can pass it to the back end in credentials, however I cant seem to find a way to verify the auth/sveltekit cookie at the back end.

I have gone through the documentation for 'auth/core' and tried to decode the token however I cant find a solution that works. I have even tried to just encode the token myself but I keep getting

```
"Error while encoding token: TypeError: "ikm"" must be an instance of Uint8Array or a string"
```

It seems this is an error relating to the AUTH_SECRET, however auth/sveltekit seems to have no problem with the secret, as it is managing the session without issues. I have tried hard coding the secret into the encode/decode parameters but still get the same error. Google has some recommendations but none have worked for me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am almost ready to ditch auth/sveltekit. Would a better solution be to encrypt the existing token using a different library, then send it as a bearer token, then decrypt at the back end? It seems a shame given auth/sveltekit is currently managing the session well at the front end.